# How to deploy an ASP.NET Core website on AWS ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-ec2

I am trying to deploy an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Angular 6 website to an ec2 instance.

I have copied the code to the server and build it using the PowerShell console.

I have tested the site using dotnet run and the site runs on https://localhost:5001/.

The security group in AWS has the following inbound port ranges open:

```
1. 80 -> 0.0.0.0/0   (HTTP)
2. 443 -> 0.0.0.0/0  (HTTPS)
```

What do I need to do to expose this site to the outside world?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not wish to add a loadbalancer, the only thing you need to do is add an additional security group rule to allow port 5001 to be accessed by 0.0.0.0/0. Might be a bit nicer if your application simply runs on port 80.

If you wish to use a loadbalancer, checkout some of the [AWS tutorials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-getting-started.html) about it.